# Getting \displayLilyMusic to output chord symbols

Tags: chords, lilypond

I have a simple jazz-style lead sheet with a melody and chord symbols.

[image]

I need to transform the input in a way that every note/chord gets its duration printed (and also its absolute pitch). For example, I want this (note that `\language` is set to `english`):

```
\relative c' {
  \time 6/8
  cs'4. b8 fs d | a'4. g8 d b | fs'2. | bar "|."
}
```

to be converted to this:

```
\absolute {
  \time 6/8
   cs''4. b'8 fs'8 d'8 |
   a'4. g'8 d'8 b8 |
   fs'2. | \bar "|."
}
```

Luckily, this is exactly what `\displayLilyMusic` does, and also lets you redirect the output to a text file.

Now I want the same for the chords, but with `\displayLilyMusic`, something like this:

```
\new ChordNames \chordmode {
  b2.:maj7.3- | g:maj7 | e:min7 |
}
```

gets converted to this:

```
\new ChordNames {
  < b' d'' fs'' as'' >2. |
  < g' b' d'' fs'' >2. |
  < e' g' b' d'' >2. |
}
```

You can see that duration is included, but chords are translated to notes. What I need is:

```
\new ChordNames {
  b2.:maj7.3- |
  g2:maj7 |
  e2:min7 |
}
```

Is there a way to get an output of the chord symbols instead of the notes?

Comment: a simpler / more logical syntax for your first chord (a minor chord with a major seventh) is :`b2.:min7+` or `b2.:m7+`

Comment: Thanks, @ElementsinSpace. I'm still learning and I would have thought that ```min7``` would make my 7th minor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Something like `g:maj7` is just syntax candy for `<g' b' d' fs'>`. `\chordmode` is a special keyword that tells the parser to create such chords. This means that after parsing the file Lilypond does not know that this was entered using `\chordmode`. (And there is no real functional difference between these two.) One might argue the Lilypond’s way of transforming chord specifications to notes to chord names is a bit stupid, but well.

Probably the way to go would be using Frescobaldi. Frescobaldi comes with it’s own Lilypond parser written in python, accessible by the `python-ly` package, which also provides a commandline tool `ly`.

Thus Frescobaldi is able to do what you want: Choose Tools->Musical Transformations->Pitches and you’ll find a point for transforming relative pitch to absolute pitch. Also under Tools->Musical Transformations->Rhythm you’ll find an option to make rhythms explicit (i.e. adding the duration to each note).

The relative to absolute thing can also be done using the commandline tool, but the explicit rhythms are supported by `python-ly` but have no option to use it from the CLI.

Comment: Thank you! And what about getting the chord back from the notes or not transforming the chords at all? Is there such functionality in ```python-ly```? I have been looking at the package, but I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: @nuncaeslupus Using Frescobaldi or python-ly does not transform chord mode into chords. So there is no need to transform it back.

Comment: I am looking at ```quickly```. It seems I would be able to get what I need using it. Thanks for directing me to the right way!

Comment: `quickly` is pretty much a somewhat early redesign of `python-ly` with all caveats that come with using early software. Basically the background is that the python lexing module `parce` has received support for lexing Lilypond code, so people behind Frescobaldi and python-ly decided to switch away from maintaining their own Lilypond lexer to using `parce`.

Comment: Actually, according to the Goal section of ```parce```'s [website](https://parce.info/overview.html#goal), "_parce_ was written to replace the LilyPond-parser in the Frescobaldi editor", so probably Lilypond code was the first language to be supported by ```parce```.

Comment: @nuncaeslupus Yes, that might be. Point is: You might run into weird situations with quickly, as it is somewhat new.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, no.  Chord input gets translated into notes (slightly annotated to mark the root of the chord and get the right octaves for the chosen inversion) during the input, and they get translated to a markup by the chord namer.  What exact input got used is lost in the process.

If you want to really cheat, you can pick off the input location of the chord event and then just read and regurgitate the input causing it.  Of course this will not reflect any transpositions or similar changes done to the music.

It would be tedious but comparatively straightforward to take the chord naming function and change it to crank out not a markup but an input string.  I don't think someone did this yet.

Comment: Thanks for your insights! I'll try ```quickly``` to be able to manipulate the original music text and transform it exactly how I need.